# How can we pass a value from the_permalink() at WordPress?

Tags: posts, permalinks

I want to pass the sub category id number from a post link `<a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>">` is there any solution to pass the value from one page to another through link.
we can pass the id as href=?id= and we can get value from  at single post as a link will be www.example.com/post1/?id=22 Which will be dynamic link of a single post and I just need www.example.com/post1/ a single link and pass the value to single-post page is that possible.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

`the_permalink()` only displays the URL for the current post in the loop. If you want to link to another post, you can use `echo get_the_permalink( 123 );`, where `123` is a post ID.

```
<a href="<?php echo get_the_permalink( 123 ) ?>">
```

Note that `the_permalink()` and `get_the_permalink()` only get URLs for *posts*. If you want to get the URL for a *category* (or tag, or other taxonomy term) you need to use `get_term_link()`:

```
<a href="<?php echo get_term_link( 123 ) ?>">
```

Comment: when i pass the link like that post link will be change to www.example.com/7-revision-v1/  that a link is not exit 404 error and other post link will also change randomly

Comment: Are you trying to link to a post or a category? Make sure you're using the correct function, as per my answer. If you are, and are getting the incorrect link, then the problem is with the ID that you're passing. You haven't said how or where you're getting that from, so I can't help with that.

Comment: I want to pass the variable $cat-id inside the post loop having link, so that I can get a $cat-id value at single-post. And also please help me to get the value at single-post.

Comment: Where does `$cat-id` come from?

Comment: that is sub-categories  id of post loop

Comment: Sorry, but I don't understand what you're talking about. You're going to need to update your question with more code, or post a new question with more information.

Comment: I have edited by question and provide code at image.